# Regex to match between a word and period

Tags: c#, regex

I wondering if anyone can help me finish a regex. I am trying to match the text after a keyword (phrase) and the period at the end of the sentence. I am close, but, no matter what I try, that period is always included.

Here is where I am currently:

```
phrase([^.]+?)\.
```

I know I could probably do something afterward like this:

```
string.replace(".","");
```

However, I would rather do everything I need via the regular expression. Can someone show me what part I am missing?

Example:

- Input: `"The current phrase blah blah blah."`
- Expected output: `"blah blah blah"`
- Current output: `"blah blah blah."` (period included.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to either use your regex and get the `Groups[1].Value` from it:

```
var s = "My phrase is here.";
var rx = new Regex(@"phrase([^.]+)\.");
Console.WriteLine(rx.Match(s).Groups[1].Value);
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/hGBDlo)

Or re-write a regex with a look-behind and access the text you need using `rx.Match(s).Value`:

```
(?<=phrase)[^.]+
```

Code:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"(?<=phrase)[^.]+");
Console.WriteLine(rx.Match(s).Value);
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3Dphrase)%5B%5E.%5D%2B&i=My%20phrase%20is%20here.)

**NOTE**: Look-behinds are resource-consuming, I'd definitely prefer the capturing group approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
var blahs = Regex.Match(input, @"phrase(.+?)\.").Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Lookbehinds and lookaheads`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) will allow you to match text before/after some other text, *but not including* the other text.  In your example, you'll want `(?<=The current phrase ).*?(?=\.)`